# Core Data: Common relationship to different types

Tags: cocoa, core-data, entity-relationship

Suppose we have two types, `House` and `Pet`. These types don't have many things in common, but they both have an `owner`. The owner is of type `Person`.

I don't want to have both `Dog` and `House` derive from a common supertype because, as I understand, Core Data won't like that with largeish data sets (a few 100K of each). If this assumption is untrue, please tell me.

Now, since Core Data doesn't like relationships without inverses, the `Person` needs an inverse for both `House`s and `Dog`s. Having two separate relationships (namely `houses` and `dogs`) seems like the obvious solution, but a person can own many, many different things (for the sake of this question, we're treating animals as things. Sorry, animals!).

I would like `Person` to have a single to-many relationship `possessions`. This does not seem to be possible with Core Data. Is dozens of relationships (one for each type of possession) really the way to go, if making `Dog` and `House` both inherit from a common superclass is not an option? Is there no such thing as a protocol for Core Data entities (so that they both could be `ownable`)? This does not seem like all too exotic a use case to me.

Am I missing something? I probably am. Tell me what, and win my gratitude :)

Comment: How are you going to use the `possessions` relationship? Do you want to add both `House` and `Pet` entities to that relationship? Or will you only be reading from that relationship?

Comment: In principle, I just need something navigable from owner to all the owner's possessions. Much more important is that every thing has a navigable relationship to its owner.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new entity called `Thing`. Add a to-one relation from `Thing` to `Person` called `owner`. Add a to-many relation from `Person` to `Thing` called `possessions`. Make them inverse of each other.

Next, make all of your things sub-entities of `Thing`.

Now, anything which is common to all things goes in the `Thing` entity and a `Person` can have an assorted collection of possessions.

Comment: As I said: I don't want to make them sub-entities of a common supertype (mainly because there may be hundreds of thousands of each thing, and I don't want them all in one table in the backing store, since I'll often need stuff like "all dogs".

Comment: I don't see where you said that in the question. Are you sure CoreData will put all entities with a common super-entity into a single table? I don't know, but that could cause problems. In any case you can add indexes to assist with searches.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made that clearer. I did have the info in that they are too different to inherit from a common supertype. I am not 100% sure about the inheritance and common table, but I've heard it multiple times.

Comment: That is correct: If Thing is the parent entity of House and Pet then all Thing/House/Pet objects are stored in a common ZTHING table.

Comment: In that case I think the best option would be to not use a relationship but to store the objectId (URI) of the parent. But it depends what you're going to do with the data. Likewise for using a relation, as you don't need an inverse but it depends what you're going to do as to what problem it might cause (like orphaned objects which should have been deleted).

Comment: Interesting idea; I'll think about that. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion storing object-IDs will cause more problems. You have to take so many things into consideration: temporary IDs, permanent IDs, there can be permanent IDs without a row in the backing store (you would get an exception if you try to access the object with this kind of ID), undo/redo, keeping everything in sync, nested contexts and so on. You are correct that entity hierarchies will end up in a single table. This might not even be so bad (performance wise). If it is you can optimize it (add indices, introduce new 1:1 relationships to offload the entity specific attributes).